# List branches sorted by creation date

Tags: git

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)'
```

The above command prints branches sorted by the date of the last commit. But how to sort by the date of the first commit? (i.e. the date when the branch was created).

Comment: The git branch does not track the date when it is created though the local reflog may have an entry of its creation. Reflogs are not pushed or cloned so they cannot be shared via common git commands.

Comment: @ElpieKay any way to iterate the tree using Python or other language and finding where and when the branch has split from the master?

Comment: Branches do not necessarily mean that there was any splitting off involved. You should [read the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to understand what branches actually are and how the history works. You could walk through the history reading merges inversed to recognize actual tree branches in the history, but that will not give you a way to attach a (branch) name to it simply due to the way branches work.

Comment: @exebook not possible unless you and every contributor always remember to create a tag or git note to record the creation when creating a new branch and to push/fetch these tags/notes afterwards. Another approach is to maintain a log file in your repo that tracks the creation of branches, which is not that good.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because Git do not record the date/time a branch was created. The "reflog" is a local only option to "rescue" this kind of information, but it only records when the tips of branches were updated in the local repository, it doesn't differentiate if a branch was created at that moment of if it already existed.

Comment: If you need this information, you can probably write an alias to tag the branch point at the same time as branching - then you'd have a record of when the branch was "created". It won't help you if multiple people create local branches with the same name and merge them together afterwards, though.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, it is not possible to find out the creation date of branch in Git.

> @ElpieKay any way to iterate the tree using Python or other language and finding where and when the branch has split from the master?

This, however, is achievable with [git-merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base). The following will print sha1 for commit which is a common ancestor of `master` and `branch`:

```
git merge-base branch master
```

Comment: `git merge-base` finds the latest common ancestor. The commit on which the new branch is created is not always the latest one.